# Correlation Id In cosmosdb - Azurediagnostic table (log analytics)

Tags: node.js, logging, azure-cosmosdb, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to correlate all the logs (log analytics table) from following flow

**APIM Gateways service(C# policy) -> Azure Functions(NodeJS code) -> Azure Cosmos DB.**

But The CorrelationId in all Log Analytics Table (AzureDiagnostics ,ApiManagementGatewayLogs and AzureFunctionAppLogs ) are empty except (ApiManagementGatewayLogs table).

Note:

1. I have configured the Azure portal for codeless logging. Logs are populating but not having correlationId.

Needs assistance to coordinate and correlate multiple component logs in the full flow using log analytics

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AFAIK**, there is no way to track `Correlation ID` as of today using **`Codeless Attach`**. But, you can definitely add `Correlation ID` to your requests and query logs in `App Insights` using that `Correlation ID`.

Below are sample Architectures that explains how to track Correlation ID across services:

**Sample Architecture 1:**

[image]

**Sample Architecture 2:**

[image]

You can follow [Structured Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/logging/unified-logging#structured-logging) to be precise to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @singhh-msft.
I can correlate with AppInsights using code but 
I am trying to pass correlation Id to cosmosdb via nodejs cosmosdb sdk to log into Azure Diagnostics table (Log Analytics table )but the correlation Id columns over queries always empty. I searching for the header to pass to populate the Azure Diagnostics  table's correlation id.

Comment: I don't see correlation ID being added by default in Azure Diagnostics table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-monitor-resource-logs. I am skeptical about it's possibility. How are you adding it?

Comment: even I am wondering how to pass it . and get my trace and error logs correlated in logs under log analytics.
**I am trying to correlate logs from apim ,function and cosmosdb **
I still searching a way to correlate logs in log analytics. as the FunctionAppLogs not having correlationID and AzureDiag. table have correlationID still its not populating, I am wondering how to correlate logs via some means

Comment: I am in fact seaching for a way via nodejs cosmosdb sdk or some configuration to push correlation id or similar to correlate logs. 
Is it possible? if yes ,how to do? in nodejs azure function ( cosmosdb sdk)?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Is there a way to correlate logs from apimanagement gateway logs,  azure diagnostic (comos db logs ) and function app logs?

Comment: As there is no Possible way currently closing this question.
Kindly refer the link for any further details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226625/correlationid.html